# Solution for eval

Tags: php

I am doing custom search for table. I have three search parameters: from, to and status. I have used `eval()` to filter result according to received parameter. Below is my code:

```
$search = ($from != "" || $to != "" || $status != "" );



if ($search) {
    if ($from != '') {
        $condition[] = '$from ==  $res["from_number"]';
    }
    if ($to != '') {
        $condition[] = '$to ==  $res["to_number"]';
    }

    if ($status != '') {
        $condition[] = '$status == $log["status"]';
    }

    $search = "if(" . implode(' && ', $condition) . '){ return false; } else { return true; }';
}
```

After getting the conditions I am using `eval`

```
if (eval($search)) {

}
```

My problem is I don't want to use `eval()`. It may cause security issues. Ladder if else is not possible, it would be very lengthy. Any other solution?

e.g. If i have passed value for status then i want check like

```
if($status == $log["status"]) {
}
```

if i have passed to & from number then it should be like:

```
if($from ==  $res["from_number"] && $to ==  $res["to_number"]) {
}
```

Comment: Why are you even using eval in the first place? Why do you need to interpret `$search` as code?

Comment: Three parameters is not a big deal.

Comment: Could you please update the question with your inputs and the expected outputs?

Comment: `eval` wouldn't pose a security issue for these concrete expressions anyway. But it's not like you couldn't just interpret the conditions right away, and collect them into `$results[]=` instead of `$condition[]=` → then check for all-thruthiness.

Comment: Yeah or just use one boolean value initially set to true... You don't really need to know if every single one was true or false, just that none were false.

Comment: How in the world did you ever even think of doing it this way?

Comment: @u_mulder In another case i have 5 param so if else not feasible

Comment: @mario I doing like that but i dont want to check condition if that param is empty, i mean if i have passed value for status then there should be only one condition which checks for status from result

Comment: @mkaatman please check the updated example you ll get idea what i want

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `eval` - it is potentially dangerous and not recommended to use.

Your code can be like this:

```
$result = false;
if ($from != "" || $to != "" || $status != "") {
    if ($from != '' && $from != $res["from_number"]) $result = true;
    if ($to != '' && $to != $res["to_number"]) $result = true;
    if ($status != '' && $status != $log["status"]) $result = true;
}           

if ($result) {
    // ........
}
```

Comment: please check the example in question, you ll get idea what i want